# Pre-filtering lists from multiple list-selectors using Ares IDE in Palm webOS

Tags: javascript, webos

I have populated two lists using listselectors in Ares, such that list ONE contains A, B, C, D and list TWO contains E, F, G, H. How can I prefilter the second list such that when item A is selected from list ONE, it prefilters list TWO to show just F,G?

The code I have so far is:

```
function FinalAssistant(argFromPusher) {
}

FinalAssistant.prototype = {
setup: function() {
    Ares.setupSceneAssistant(this);
},
cleanup: function() {
    Ares.cleanupSceneAssistant(this);
},
listSelector1Change: function(inSender, event) {
    this.$.getListSelector2.choices["F"]

    },  
};
```

---

*edit to add:*

I have added the callback function and cleanup method but its still not passing the parameters F & G.

The code is as follows

```
FinalAssistant.prototype = {
setup: function() {
    Ares.setupSceneAssistant(this);
    this.controller.listen("listSelector1", Mojo.Event.listSelector1Tap, this.listSelector1Tap.bindAsEventListener(this));
},
cleanup: function() {
    Ares.cleanupSceneAssistant(this);
    Mojo.Event.stopListening(this.controller.listSelector1,Mojo.Event.listSelector1Tap,this.listSelector1Tap)

},

listSelector1Tap: function(inSender, event) {
    switch (event.choices.label)
{
    case 'A':
        this.listModel2.choices = [{label: "F"}, {label: "G"}];
        this.controller.modelChanged(this.listModel2);
        break;
    case 'B':
        this.listModel2.choices = [{label: "H"}, {label: "I"}];
        this.controller.modelChanged(this.listModel2);
        break;    
    }    
},
};
```

the Mojo Log info error says Mojo.Event.listen 'target' parameter must be defined

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is fairly straightforward.  First, since it doesn't appear to be, you need to set up a callback for `Mojo.Event.listTap` like so in your setup function:

```
this.controller.listen('list1', Mojo.Event.listTap, this.list1Tap.bindAsEventListener(this))
```

And then later you need to do a `stopListening` in your cleanup to avoid leaving a zombie listener.

Also, since I don't see it given here, you'll need somewhere to store the list model, viz. the objects that contain the items for your list.  Here I'll assume it's called `list2Model` for `list2`.

As for `list1Tap`, you'll need something like:

```
list1Tap: function(event) {
    switch (event.item.label)
    {
        case: 'A':
            this.list2Model.items = [{label: "F"}, {label: "G"}];
            this.controller.modelChanged(this.list2Model);
            break;
    }
},
```

And that should do it.  Obviously there's a lot more structure you'll need to get it working 100%, but that's how to do the part you asked about.